# Upgrading from Umbraco 7.4.3 to 9

Tags: web, umbraco, updating

I've been tasked with updating our companies site from 7.4.3 to the latest version of 9. I've spent many, many hours trying this. I've been following step by step guides and can't even get past the first step of updating to 7.6.14. I managed to get the website to run locally and show the Umbraco update page, but when I try to update it immediately cancels out.

(the log has this message:

_shutDownMessage=CONFIG change HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown HostingEnvironment caused shutdown )

I saw other people having this problem but couldn't find an actual solution. I also tried uploading to dev server and running it from there, but the website is a big mess of stuff and the NuGet umbraco update moves so much stuff around I'm not sure what I actually need to replace on the dev folder. Does anybody know what files I need to keep for this to work?

Am I better off starting with a fresh version of Umbraco 9.2 and remaking 8 years of web content from scratch? Please... save me :S

Comment: How complex is your existing content? Like, are you using grids? Custom datatypes?

Comment: Third party components? If nothing too complex then yes, I'd start from scratch. You can export alot to files using uSync and either try to import to a fresh v9 or even create your own code to export/import whatever content you deem important (or even just importable).

Comment: It's very complex, it's a Frankenstein's monster of 8+ years of web development by a umber of different people, and there is no one left who knows what everything in the project folder is :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your plan is to move to Umbraco 9, then you shouldn't waste your time with Umbraco 7 upgrades as there is no direct upgrade path from any version of [Umbraco 7 to Umbraco 8](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Fundamentals/Setup/upgrading/migrating-to-v8#migrating-content-to-umbraco-8) or Umbraco 9.

If you have time, then you can try spinning up a fresh Umbraco 8 website, create all your Umbraco objects there, do the data migration from Umbraco 7 to 8, and then you can spin up a new Umbraco 9 website, try migrating your Umbraco 8 objects/data into Umbraco 9. This is the recommended option by Umbraco HQ.

I have got a similar Umbraco 7 project and as I don't have time, I'm planning to spin up a fresh Umbraco 9 website, create all the necessary Umbraco 9 objects according to the latest Umbraco best practices, do the data migration by writing some custom code, similar to [this approach](https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-i-migrated-my-umbraco-v7-site-to-v8-part-2-content/).

If you really want to do your Umbraco 7 upgrades, you might try some smaller upgrades as there are a lot of breaking changes [from Umbraco 7.4.3 to Umbraco 7.6.14.](https://our.umbraco.com/download/releases/compare?from=7.4.3&to=7.6.14)

Additional notes;

- A lot of legacy code has been removed completely when implementing the Umbraco 8 changes - this includes a lot of code clean up compared to Umbraco 7.
- New APIs were introduced as well as complete new Umbraco backoffice features, i.e. Infinite Editing, Content Apps, Language Variants etc.
- From Umbraco 8 to Umbraco 9, initially, the only big difference was they moved the source code from .NET Framework to .NET 5.
- You can not do an upgrade from a .NET Framework project to .NET 5.
- [See my blog](https://nurhak-kaya.blogspot.com/2020/07/umbraco-v8-upgrade-from-v7-developer.html) for more details about my Umbraco 8 upgrade experience from Umbraco 7.

Comment: So, I have the Umbraco content exported via uSync... Do I now go through each step with a fresh install of Umbraco? like do I need to get 7.6.14 and then point it at the database and then do 7 latest, etc?
How do I point a fresh install at the database? do I just copy in the connection strings?

Comment: Don't use any of the Umbraco 7 website connection string - just create a new web project, do your Umbraco 8 or 9 installation in your new web project then when you do your new Umbraco 8 / 9 db setup use a new connection string for your new DB. After that create all the other things that you will need for your Umbraco 8 or 9 website (Document types, custom data types (all custom code if necessary). When you are ready, then you can focus on data migration from your Umbraco 7 db into your new Umbraco 8 or 9 db.

Comment: For the data migration, I believe you can use yoıur uSync objects or you can create your own data migration code, like mentioned here: https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-i-migrated-my-umbraco-v7-site-to-v8-part-2-content/

Comment: @DarrenCrisp; if my answer has helped you, please remember to mark it as useful(upvote button) or mark it as the correct answer.